# arch не грузится после обновления

Tags: archlinux

Часа два назад обновил ядро linux-lts. После перезагрузки вижу красивенную надпись от asus-ов и всё. Перейти в bios через f1-f12, del не получается. Загрузочную флешку арча ноут тоже игнорирует. Как можно загрузить систему и сделать откат? Модель ноутбука - asus x541s

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Я пошел таким путём - достал ссд-диск из ноута, после этого "заработала" загрузочная флешка. После примонтировал носитель через usb, далее - arch-chroot, [downgrade](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/downgrade/), profit.

[Тут](https://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/18618/?page=1#post-206648) предложили попробовать несколько комбинаций клавиш для входа в bios. Может кому и пригодится.